# How to make Feign POST request without a request body and with query params?

Tags: http-post, apache-httpclient-4.x, feign

I am using Feign with the [Apache Http Client](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/tree/release-9.5.0/httpclient) and I would like to support the following jax-rs interface:

```
@POST
@Path("/do_something")
void doSomething(@QueryParam("arg") String arg);
```

But, [ApacheHttpClient](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/release-9.5.0/httpclient/src/main/java/feign/httpclient/ApacheHttpClient.java) uses a [RequestBuilder](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/RequestBuilder.html), which converts query parameters for requests without a body/entity into a UrlEncodedFormEntity.

I am converting my APIs to jax-rs, and I do not want to break backwards compatibility. Is there a way to use Feign without adjusting my API? Will the OkHttp or Ribbon clients support POSTs with query params and no body/entity? Is there another java jax-rs client that will support this?

Also, is there a reason why RequestBuilder turns query params into a UrlEncodedFormEntity? Is there an alternative HttpUriRequest builder within the apache-httpclient library that doesn't do this? RequestBuilder's build method has the following lines of code:

```
if (entity == null && (HttpPost.METHOD_NAME.equalsIgnoreCase(method) || HttpPut.METHOD_NAME.equalsIgnoreCase(method))) {
  entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters, HTTP.DEF_CONTENT_CHARSET);
} else {
  // omitted expected behavior
}
```

Before switching to Feign, my code constructed a HttpUriRequest with something similar to the following:

```
URI uri = new URIBuilder()
        .setScheme("https")
        .setHost("localhost")
        .setPath("service/do_something")
        .addParameter("arg", "value")
        .build();
HttpUriRequest request = new HttpPost(uri);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to break the API slightly and maintain support for the `@QueryParam`, then you could define a request interceptor on the feign client that adds a plain text entity/body to the request:

```
.requestInterceptor(template -> {
  if (template.method().equals(HttpPost.METHOD_NAME) && template.queries().keySet().size() > 0 && template.body() == null) {
    template.body(" ");
  }
})
```

Then, your API would change with the following:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Path("/do_something")
void doSomething(@QueryParam("arg") String arg);
```

But, this breaks the API since the server now expects/consumes a POST message with a plain text entity/body.

I think the same could be accomplished without the requestInterceptor and with Feign's `@Body` template:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Body(" ")
@Path("/do_something")
void doSomething(@QueryParam("arg") String arg);
```

But, this means that your API would have to include Feign rather than pure jax-rs annotations.